# Linkedin developer api access giving Unauthorized while page fetch api

Tags: linkedin-api

I have implemented LinkedIn developer API in my organization, for page fetch and share posts on the LinkedIn page. Firstly I generate access token and then access LinkedIn page fetch API :

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationAcls?q=roleAssignee&role=ADMINISTRATOR&projection=(elements*(*,roleAssignee~(localizedFirstName, localizedLastName), organization~(localizedName)))

Since last week I am facing an error when I generate a new access token from my account and try to fetch page LinkedIn it randomly gives me an Unauthorized exception. When I check the token from LinkedIn token introspection API it's providing me status as revoked. Why is this happening? I can't find a reason anywhere.

#linkedin